# How to fire query for loaded documents in marklogic server?

Tags: marklogic

I loaded some xml documents to marklogic server through load content, `xquery` and through `admin` interface. I did some sample example for fetching document data, manipulating and all through `xquery` console.

But after loading document to server, How to put query for them through xquery??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This question is undecipherable.

Answer (score 1):

There are number of ways to do this, but it depends how you stored your XML files:

First, if your documents are in one dicrectory 'MyDirectory', you may use `xdmp:directory("/MyDirectory/")` to return all XML files content.

Second, if you don't know directory and your root element for all XML files is same 'ROOT', you should use `/ROOT` to get all related XML files.

Third, if you know the URI of your XML file '/MyDirectory/abc.xml' use `doc("/MyDirectory/abc.xml")`

Fourth, if you want to get everthing from your DB, use `doc()`

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you. Let suppose i loaded document from "/root/tmp/sample" directory to server. Now suggest me how i will fire query on them through xquery. Please

Comment: Just run doc() command from your qconsole by selecting same Marklogic DB where you have copied your XML file. For more details go http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/qconsole.pdf